# How to use groupby in linq sql

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by

I am trying to group a list and using ToDictionary to achieve this which works:

```
var levels = ids.GroupBy(f => f.Id).
    ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().Name);
```

The problem is: in the string "Name" the last char is a number i.e. 2 or 5 or 7 etc.

I do NOT want to select the first but I want to select "Name" with the MAX number. How can i achieve this.  example of Name can be: "abd-hbb-les3" , "abd-hbb-les1" , "abd-hbb-les6"

Comment: You can order desc by name and take first element, can't you?

Comment: When you say you want to "select" the "name" with the max number, you mean inside the ToDictionary? or just the one with the max value altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every group simply select the name with the maximum last character of the string. Like this:

```
var levels = ids.
    GroupBy(f => f.Id).
    ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.First(i => i.Name.Last() == g.Max(j => j.Name.Last())).Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in the following way:

```
var levels = ids.GroupBy(f => f.Id).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
    g => g.First( x=> x.Name.Last() == g.Max( y=> y.Name.Last())).Name);
```

assuming that it's really about **the last letter** so it's not possible to have a two (or more) digits at the end e.g.:

```
abd-hbb-les16 //will not work with the above code
```